# Map a value from one arbitrary range to another within the limits of the given data type

Tags: c#, floating-point

Normally you can convert a value `input` from one range `[inputMin, inputMax]` to another range `[outputMin, outputMax]` using the following formula:

```
output = (input-inputMin) * ((outputMax-outputMin)/(inputMax-inputMin)) + outputMin
```

But what if `inputMax = double.MaxValue` and `inputMin = double.MinValue`? Then `inputMax - inputMin == double.PositiveInfinity` and the whole formula goes down the crapper.

Is there a better way to do this conversion under the following restrictions?

- completely within the limits of the data type
- for arbitrary ranges
- if `inputMax >= outputMax` and `inputMin <= outputMin`

Comment: You could probably use [Microsoft's BigRational library](https://github.com/MicrosoftArchive/bcl/blob/master/Libraries/BigRational/BigRationalLibrary/BigRational.cs) for this. The easiest way to get it is via NuGet. Hasn't been updated for donkey's years, but it should still work fine.

Comment: As I said, I want to stay within the given data type. Mostly for performance reasons, but also because I'm simply interested in the problem at hand.

Comment: You can't stay within the data type without being subject to that data type's limitations. You are asking for arbitrary precision and clearly that will require more than the 64 bits (or 80 bits in some cases) of a `double`.

Comment: I'm not requiring arbitrary precision. The range is getting smaller (check the restrictions), so there is a loss of precision anyways. Because the range is becoming smaller, I'm pretty sure there should be a solution to the problem.

Comment: You could check for overflow and use a scaled version of the factor:
`(outputMax/2-outputMin/2)/(inputMax/2-inputMin/2)`

Comment: But by choosing `inputMax-inputMin` as a value approaching zero and `outputMax-outputMin` as a value approaching `double.MaxValue` the division will produce a value well outside the range of a `double`.

Comment: @gammatester: `input-inputMin` needs to be scaled too, as it could overflow. And `outputMax/2-outputMin/2` could underflow (either to zero or simply losing precision), although that suggests an abnormal output range.

Comment: @MatthewWatson: Criteria in the question make the input range wider than the output range.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: What do you think about https://gist.github.com/drauch/c6c759a0f260c009ccaa75522c149885 ?

Comment: If `input-inputMin` overflows, I can use `inputMax-input` instead, subtract `-outputMax` instead of adding `+outputMin` and it should be fine as well?!

Comment: A single scale factor cannot suffice. `inputMax-inputMin` might be large, say around 2^1000, while `outputMax-outputMin` might be small, say around 2^-1000. Then the scale factor would be around 2^-2000, which is too small to be represented in the IEEE 64-bit binary floating-point format. So a solution is going to involve at least two scalings.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid `inputMax - inputMin` overflow to infinity, scale `input, inputMin, inputMax`, all by `/2`.  That is expected to be exact except for some small values: sub-normals with least significant bit set.

```
x = input/2;  // scale `input` also
x0 = inputMin/2;
x1 = inputMax/2;
dx = x1 - x0;
```

---

[@aka.nice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52433020/map-a-value-from-one-arbitrary-range-to-another-within-the-limits-of-the-given-d/52438291?noredirect=1#comment91856333_52451793) well identified **limitations** to the improved precision approach below.  Will review later.

---

To maintain precision is tricky yet forming the [interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation) in a x-interpret fashion has advantages with FP math.  The main idea is not to form some small `y` from `y-mx*b` as that does the addition after multiplication.  Any addition/subtract is prone to serious loss of precision due to cancellation.

```
y = (x - x_intercept)*slope
```

The x-intercept `x_intercept = (x1*y2 - x2*y1)/(y2 - y1)` has its own set of issues.  When possible this should be done in extended math.  Barring that, we can take advantage that for real life applications, the `x_intercept` is not expected to be extreme and so saves us some precision in `x - x_intercept` when it matters most (`y` will be smallish).

```
y0 = outputMin/2;
y1 = outputMax/2;
dy = y1 - y0;

// Avoid (y1*x0 - y0*x1)/dy to prevent overflow in the multiplications
x_intercept = y1/dy*x0 - y0/dy*x1;
y = (x - x_intercept)/dx*dy;
output = 2*y; // scale `output` at the end.
```

Special cases like `outputMin == outputMax` can be handled with a test as needed.

This approach is similar to [@aka.nice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52438291/2410359).  Yet instead of a middle `x`, code looks to calculate  the x-intercept.

Comment: x_intercept is more robust than x_middle indeed wrt cancellation, but I will try to exhibit tricky cases when we don't use extended precision...

Comment: Take input in `[-double.MaxValue,double.MaxValue]` and map it to `[double.MaxValue/4*3,double.MaxValue]`, that will reject x_intercept to minus infinity (overflow)

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is pivot around middle:

```
inputMiddle = 0.5*inputMax + 0.5*inputMin
```

then, via the mid range of input:

```
inputMidRange = 0.5*inputsMax - 0.5*inputMin
```

compute how far away from middle is the input (between -1 and 1):

```
howFar = (input-inputMiddle) / inputMidRange
```

then via the output middle and output mid range, homothetically report this to the output

```
output = howFar * outputMidRange + outputMiddle
```

As noted by Eric, this may be subject to underflow problems if some of the interval bounds are already subnormals, but even down to twice the smallest subnormal, this should still work.

**EDIT**

The formulation above is an answer about overflow, but still have problem of catastrophic cancellation in the operation `(input-inputMiddle)`.

For example for mapping `[0,double.MaxValue]`, to `[0,double.MaxValue/2]` all the "small" values will be projected on `outputMin`, though a simple `input/2` operation would have lead to a correct output...

Comment: Should not `input` also be scaled by 0.5 else `input-inputMiddle` looks wrong?

Comment: @chux, no it should not be scaled. It cannot overflow. The distance to middle cannot exceed `inputMidRange`. It cannot exceed `double.MaxValue`, because the whole range cannot exceed `2*double.MaxValue`. You can check that `inputMin -> howFar=-1 -> -outputMidRange+outputMiddle = outputMin`, `inputMiddle -> howFar = 0 -> outputMiddle`, `inputMax -> howFar=1 -> +outputMidRange+outputMiddle->outputMax`.

Comment: NMDV, yet the suggested scaling of `input` was not to prevent overflow. It was my mistake to preserve scale.  I too was trying to determine why the DV.